# click element when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, onclick

I have this list:

```
<ul class="titles clearfix">

 <li class="opened">Billing Address</li>
 <li class="">Shipping Address</li>
 <li class="">Review Order</li>

</ul>
```

And a button:

```
<a href="#">Next</a>
```

What I want to do is, when I click on "Next" to simulate a click on "Shipping address" and If I click again to simulate a click on "Review Order".

I have tried this:

```
    jQuery("a.next-checkout").click(function(){
     jQuery("ul.titles li").click().next(); 
    return false;
    });
```

But when I click it goest straight to the last one from the list and I want to go one by one.

Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: You need to use raw domElements, try `jQuery("ul.titles li")[0].click()` to trigger the click on the first element it matched.

Comment: something like this? url: http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/KzyAY/42/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

***This is doing what you exactly need.***

```
$('a.next-checkout').on('click', function () {
    $('.titles li.opened').next().trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

---

***This snippet amplifies repetitive click event.***

```
$('a.next-checkout').on('click', function () {
    var nextLi = $('.titles li.opened').next().length ? $('.titles li.opened').next() : $('.titles li:first');
    $('.titles').find(nextLi).trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/staddx48/)

Answer (score 3):

The [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method should work if you are trying to "simulate" a click.

```
$('#your-selector').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I've used this instead of jQuery("ul.titles li").click().next(); but it functions the same way, nothing is changed.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look and make a demo in a few. Driving home at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to your question. - Click on "Next" to simulate a click on "Shipping address" and If I click again to simulate a click on "Review Order".

```
<ul class="titles clearfix">

<li class="opened">Billing Address</li>
<li class="s">Shipping Address</li>
<li class="r">Review Order</li>

</ul>

<a href="#">Next</a>


var i = 0;
$("a").click(function(){

  if(i == 0)$("li.r").trigger("click");
  if(i == 1)$("li.s").trigger("click");
  i++;
});

$("li").click(function(){ console.log($(this).text() + " clicked")});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sy36693u/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To get about this kind of a scenario, apart for triggering the click for the li element, you will also need to keep a track of the currently selected li. Below code may e helpful:

```
var curr;
var first_li=$('li:first', 'ul');;

$("#next").click(function () {

if(!curr)
{
    curr=first_li;
}
else
{
  curr=curr.next('li').length ? curr.next('li') : first_li;
}
curr.trigger('click');
});


$('li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```